# Сортировка массива по просмотрам из файлов

Tags: php, массивы

Имею массив - dump.txt, в котором 999 строк:

id|path_to_image.jpg, например:

1|images/some.jpg

2|images/some_other.jpg

...

999|images/some_999.jpg

Также имею папку views с 999 файлами названиями id, в которых пишется кол-во просмотров, например,

2.txt с содержимым 100

3.txt с содержимым 55

...

999.txt с содержимым 150

И вот возник вопрос: как можно отсортировать этот массив по количеству просмотров (популярности)?

Спасибо

Comment: в sql нельзя перейти? Так проще будет все держать все в базе и обрабатывать

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким образом, но как уже советовали в комментариях - лучше перейти на какую нибудь базу данных, ибо при большом к-стве этих самых файлов php будет кушать очень много оперативки. вот сам код:

```
function sortImages(string $path_to_dump, string $views_dir, $separator = '|') {

  $data = file_get_contents($path_to_dump);
  $items = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
  $images = [];
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if(strlen($item) > 0 && false !== strpos($item, $separator)) {
      list($image_id, $image_path) = explode($separator, $item);
      $image_count_views = 0;
      $image_views_path = $views_dir . $image_id . '.txt';
      if(file_exists($image_views_path)) {
        $image_count_views = (int) file_get_contents($image_views_path);
      }
      $images[] = [
        'path' => $image_path,
        'views_count' => $image_count_views,
      ];
    }
  }

  usort($images, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['views_count'] < $b['views_count'];
  });

  return $images;
}

print_r(
  sortImages('dump.txt', 'stats_views/')
);
```

На выходе получим отсортированый многомерный массив.